# usbip service setup PID file

Tags: command-line, server, bash, kernel, services

I have this config in my `/lib/systemd/system/usbip.service` file, but I want the service to write a PID file to `/var/run/usbipd.pid`.

```
[Unit]
Description=usbip client
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/lib/linux-tools/$(uname -r)/usbip attach -r 10.10.10.90 -b $(/usr/lib/linux-tools/$(uname -r)/usbip list -r 10.10.10.90 | grep '0403:6001' | cut -d: -f1)"
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "/usr/lib/linux-tools/$(uname -r)/usbip detach --port=$(/usr/lib/linux-tools/$(uname -r)/usbip port | grep '<Port in Use>' | sed -E 's/^Port ([0-9][0-9]).*/\1/')"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I found an article with this information:

> `-P FILE`, `--pid FILE`: Write process id to FILE.
>  If no FILE specified, use `/var/run/usbipd.pid`

I don't know where and how to put this in the `usbip.service` file.

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking `sh` in your `Exec*=` lines, but passing it a bunch of `bash`isms that `sh` does not understand

Your life would be simpler if your `Exec*=` statement just referred to `bash` scripst, and you did all your dancing around in the `bash` scripts. E.g `ExecStart=/opt/local/startup`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I have no idea what your talking about. How does this apply to the config file, can you give an example?